# what it means var lineColor = { red: 'blue', blue: 'red' }[lineColor];

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```
 $('#toggle-linecolor').click(function () {
        chart.yAxis[0].update({
            lineColor: lineColor
        });
        lineColor = { red: 'blue', blue: 'red' }[lineColor];
    });
```

Comment: what is `chart` ? which library provides it ? Anyhow it just seems that it reverse line colors...

Comment: It's accessing an object property by a key defined in a variable, just like `someObject[keyName]`.

Comment: @pawel but here's {red: 'blue', blue: 'red'}[linecolor] what does it actually with object?

Comment: lineColor = { red: 'red', blue: 'blue' }[lineColor];

Comment: could not understand why this [lineColor] is used in last

Answer (score 3):

It toggles between `'red'` and `'blue'`.

Given you start off with:

```
var lineColor = 'red';
```

Executing this will change `lineColor` to 'blue'

```
lineColor = { red: 'blue', blue: 'red' }[lineColor];
// The property [red] of that object has a value of 'blue'

lineColor // <--- 'blue'
```

Execute it again, it will toggles the value to 'red'

```
lineColor = { red: 'blue', blue: 'red' }[lineColor];
// The property [blue] of that object has a value of 'red'

lineColor // <---- 'red'
```

Comment: Tao please explain how it toggle..............i can not get.  could i used more than 2 colors in obect

Comment: A quick hint is, say,  you have `var p = { red: 'blue', blue: 'red' }`. Take the property `p['blue']` returns you "red". Vice-versa, you take `p['red']` it returns you "blue". :) Nice trick, isn't it?

Comment: Note: `p.red = 'blue'`  is equivalent to `p['red'] = 'blue'`. You can access the property by either way.

Answer (score 0):

It swaps/toggles the color. red --> blue, blue --> red

```
lineColor = 'blue';
lineColor = { red: 'red', blue: 'blue' }[lineColor]; // 'red'
```

is the same as

```
lineColor = { red: 'red', blue: 'blue' }.blue; // 'red'
```

Comment: lineColor = { red: 'red', blue: 'blue' }[lineColor]; 
     
could not understand why this [lineColor] is used in last

Answer (score 0):

It's a clever way to implement toggle as a one liner. You could unpack it like this:

```
var lineColor = 'red';
function toggleColor(){
    chart.yAxis[0].update({
        lineColor: lineColor
    });
    var opposites = { red : 'blue', blue : 'red' };
    if( lineColor == 'red' ){
        lineColor = opposites.red; // assigns 'blue' to lineColor
    }
    else if( lineColor == 'blue' ){
        lineColor = opposites.blue; // assigns 'red' to lineColor
    }

    // but you can shorten the above if/else statement to:
    lineColor = opposites[ lineColor ];

    // which can be shortened to this if you don't want to 
    // assign the opposites object to a variable:
    lineColor = { red: 'blue', blue: 'red' }[lineColor];
}
```

EDIT afer comment: You can use more than two colors creating a looping sequence:

```
opposites = { red : 'green', green : 'yellow', yellow : 'blue', blue : 'red' };
```

so if the current color is red change to green, if green change to yellow, if yellow to blue, and if blue to red: http://jsfiddle.net/p3bw04vw/

Comment: thanks pawel I got it. Can I use more than 2 colors in lineColor Object

Comment: I think that by definition toggle means switching between two states, but you could use more colors, you just need to create a chain of succeeding colors (see edited answer).